# Android Compose show and hide keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable function with `TextField`:

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
TextField(
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Search,
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onSearch = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
        )
    )
```

and I need to show keyboard from inside of composable function as well as outside of it when I click on other button which is not part of composable content. Basically I wanna call `hideKeyboard()` from my fragment.

I tried to use livedata inside composable:

```
val shouldShowKeyBoard by shouldShowSearchKeyBoard.observeAsState()
```

and I can do `focusManager.clearFocus()` to hide keyboard but I'm not sure how to show it programmatically for specific compose `TextField`

What's the "compose" way to manage hide/show keyboard?

Answer (score 17):

You can perform some action on state changes and you can do it using the [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).
For example you can use the `LaunchedEffect` function, where as a `key` you can pass a state you want to listen.

```
LaunchedEffect(booleanValue) {
    //...do something
}
```

You can use a ViewModel to set a boolean value and something like:

```
// initialize focus reference to be able to request focus programmatically
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
LaunchedEffect(viewModel.showKeyboard) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it },
    modifier = Modifier
        // add focusRequester modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
)
```

Just a note:
to hide the keyboard you can also use:

```
   val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

   TextField(
     //...
     keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onSearch = { keyboardController?.hide() }
    )
```

Use the method `focusManager.clearFocus()` to dismiss the keyboard and clear the focus.

Comment: Working solution Thanks @Gabriele
Can you help me out on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73650798/how-pass-parcelable-object-with-new-version-of-compose-navigation?noredirect=1#comment130059237_73650798

Answer (score 1):

There is also an option to use the default keyboard action after your own action. I have a search `TextField` which on Done click triggers the search function and then hides the keyboard. I achieved keyboard hiding with calling `this.defaultKeyboardAction(ImeAction.Done)` after my action.

```
SearchTextField(
    textFieldState = searchState,
    placeholder = stringResource(R.string.common_search),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
        onSearchDone()
        this.defaultKeyboardAction(ImeAction.Done) <-- This hides the keyboard
    })
)
```

With a search action it would have to be like this:

```
SearchTextField(
    textFieldState = searchState,
    placeholder = stringResource(R.string.common_search),
    imeAction = ImeAction.Search,
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = {
        onSearchDone()
        this.defaultKeyboardAction(ImeAction.Done)
    })
)
```

ImeAction.Search does not hide the keyboard but the done action does.

Answer (score 0):

to add on Gabriele's answer, you will need `val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }`
or you will get an exception