# How to toggle IME keyboard open/close in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my app, I have a `TextField` and a button which should show/hide the IME keyboard. I have read all about controlling the soft keyboard and how to show or hide it, but not how to **toggle**. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124822/android-compose-show-and-hide-keyboard) post is related, but not exactly what I'm asking for.

The problem I have is that I need to keep track of when the keyboard has been opened and closed. It's possible to open the keyboard by tapping on the `TextField` of course, and it's possible to close it by pressing the back button. I can't find any hooks or callbacks for those actions, so I can assign `isKeyboardOpen` boolean.

Because of that, I can toggle the keyboard from the `Toggle keyboard!` button, but as soon as I "manually" open it (tap on the text field) or close it (press the back button), the toggle button state can't be updated and I need to press it twice for it to show/hide the keyboard.

So far I had tried the following:

1. [`BackHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#BackHandler(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0)) - no effect
2. [`Modifier.pointerInput(Unit)`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#tapping) with `detectTapGestures` - those callbacks are never hit on tapping the `TextField`
3. [`onKeyEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/key/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onKeyEvent(kotlin.Function1)) and `onPreviewKeyEvent` - they seem to be for hardware keyboard key presses only. I tried to intercept the back press, as we'd done it in the Android Views world: `action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`, but no luck

Here's the code for those two elements, as illustrated in the gif below:

```
                Surface {

                var isKeyboardOpen by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

                Column {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        isKeyboardOpen = !isKeyboardOpen
                        if (isKeyboardOpen) keyboardController?.show() else keyboardController?.hide()
                    }
                    ) {
                        Text("Toggle keyboard!")
                    }

                    //...

                    BackHandler(isKeyboardOpen) {
                        Log.d("TextField", "backPressed - never called")
                    }

                    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

                    TextField(
                        value = text,
                        onValueChange = { text = it },
                        modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectTapGestures(
                                onTap = { Log.d("TextField", "onTap - never called") },
                                onPress = { Log.d("TextField", "onPress - never called") },
                            )
                        }.onKeyEvent { event ->
                            // callback never hit
                            if (event.type == KeyEventType.KeyUp && event.key == Key.Back) {
                                //....
                            }
                            true
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
```

[Gif of trying to toggle keyboard open/closed from a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3tBK.gif)

How can I implement keyboard toggle button in compose? Is it even possible?

Comment: Maybe one of these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/soft-keyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android

Comment: @Johann thanks! Although those look like Android View-based solutions. I managed to get it working eventually with [this proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533584/7707818) but it kind of blends compose and views - basically checking the height of the current window, and the keyboard which I think is how those view-based approaches solve it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WindowInsets to detect whether keyboard is open or close.

Follow [these](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/) instructions to add and setup Accompanist Insets Library.

Once set up you can create you button like this.

```kotlin
val insets = LocalWindowInsets.current
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

Button(onClick = {
    if (insets.ime.isVisible) keyboardController?.hide() else keyboardController?.show()
}) {
    Text("Toggle keyboard!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would be good to use a Compose solution, but using the code above, my toggle button only hides the keyboard and won't show it :( I'm not sure why?

Comment: I tried this code in my app and it worked fine. Have you added`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` and wrapped your top level composable using `ProvideWindowInsets`?

Comment: I hadn't done `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` and that seems to have fixed it now! It does seem to alter the layout slightly (the top padding seems to be disregarded and the views shoot right to the top of the screen) so might need a workaround for that and understand what `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` does exactly. Thanks for your solution!!

Comment: It just gives you app the entire screen area to draw upon. They call it going `edge-to-edge`. If you don't want this you can wrap your top level composable inside a box and add a `Modifier.systemBarsPadding()`. This will push your app content outside the system bars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KeyboardVisibilityEvent library for that

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
    getActivity(),
    new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
           // do your thing here !!
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure this can be easily incorporated with Compose though? It's an option, but I'm looking for a compose-only approach.